# KiokuDB on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, persistence, kiokudb

I wonder if anybody has been able to successfully use [KiokuDB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KiokuDB) on Windows. Having ActivePerl 5.12.2, I did not find it pre-compiled in ppm repositories. Using cpan, it stopped during testing [File::NFSLock](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aNFSLock). I was able to install it with notest, though.

Simple test below seems to work as documented:

```
package Person;
use Moose;

has ['name', 'age'] => (is => 'ro');

package main;

use Data::Dump;
use KiokuDB;

my $dir = KiokuDB->connect("hash");

{
    my $scope   = $dir->new_scope;
    my $obj = Person->new(name => 'Joe', age => 34);

    my $data_id = $dir->store($obj);

    warn $data_id;   # 6702A424-6BF6-1014-B0F5-EC4CE5BB15D7

    my $got = $dir->lookup($data_id);
    dd $got;         # bless({ age => 34, name => "Joe" }, "Person")
}
```

Anyone used it for something larger on Windows, say with DBI backend? Do you think it is stable/usable enough to use for some smaller project?

Please provide at least some details of your kind of usage, so I have an idea that matches my plans.

Comment: Any chance of using Strawberry instead of ActiveState? Most module installation problems just go away if you do : )

Comment: @Hugmeir - I have far too many applications running on AS, so the retest on Strawberry would be costly/problematic. And I don't have installation problems, it does install and its test suite runs without a failure. Notest has to be used because of failing test in one downstream dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been successfully using KiokuDB on windows via [Strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

I've yet to find a perl module (that isn't obviously linux specific) that doesn't Just Work under it. I've not exactly gone out of my way to try odd things, but KiokuDB, DBIx::Class and Catalyst and all their included deps worked without trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using KiokuDB for one smaller project these days and it works well for me, too.  These two answers also support my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed with cpan force option, and it works like a charm; and yes, it's stable enough for my applications

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a little more details on this. What backend are you using, what perl version, any experience/problems encountered?